# Tinymce, causing everything to be wrapped in strong tags

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have recently started using TinyMCE in a project and when I use the bold functionality in the editor it looks great, however when I go out to my index page (rails) and look at the table containing my objects, anything below the one utilizing the bold is wrapped in strong tags. Causing strangeness with my javascript. Is Tinymce bugged or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using sanitize() instead of raw when rendering.